# Limitations of Key and Label for Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure, app-config, azureportal, azure-app-configuration

I started using Azure App Configuration service and Feature Flags functionality in my project. I am using the Azure portal to create the feature flag with some name and label.
When I enter long feature flag name I get the following error
[image]

The error does not specify the limitation around the use of name and the label of the feature flag.  I tried to find in the Azure documentation but couldn't locate it. How can I get these limitation?

Answer (score 0):

The App Configuration server side does not enforce any restriction on creating a feature flag. It's the same as creating a regular key-value. The error you showed is not from App Configuration, but from your code. It will be helpful if you can share the actual error from App Configuration.

A regular key-value becomes a feature flag by following a convention, which you can find in the link below:
https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration/tree/main/docs/FeatureManagement